# C Loop Patterns

Tags: c

I've got my code half way working but I can't get the other half to work.

What pattern needs to look like:

> 1sssss
>   s2ssss
>   ss3sss
>   sss4ss
>   ssss5s
>   sssss6

What my pattern looks like:

> 1
>   s2
>   ss3
>   sss4
>   ssss5
>   sssss6

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j, k, num;

    printf("Enter number ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            if (j != i) {
                printf("s");
            }
        }

        printf("%d ", j-1);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess you made a mistake in this one.

```
     for(int j=1; j<=i ; ++j)
```

`i` should be until the `num` variable, because you need print `num` times.

Hope this helps

Comment: why is everybody assuming that this answer actually produces the expected output?=! it **doesn't**. You get 6 lines of `sssss6`. Please add at least the point with the else condition, otherwise the upvotes are simply not justified...

Comment: as @MongZhu explained, there also error logic there, you should print the inside j loop

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in your for loop. You needed an else clause as well as print i not j-1. This code runs correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, num;

    printf("Enter number ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= num; ++j)
        {

            if (j != i)
            {
                printf("s");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d", i);
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop outputs `i - 1` characters instead of `num` characters.

```
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
    {
        if (j != i) {
            printf("s");
        }
    }

    printf("%d ", j-1);
```

Moreover after the loop the last outputted character in a line is always a digit equal to `i`.

The program can look the following way as it is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char c = 's';
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned int n;

        printf( "Enter a positive number less than %u (0 - exit): ", Base );

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || ( n %= Base ) == 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
            {
                putchar( i == j ? j + 1 + '0' : c );
            }
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a positive number less than 10 (0 - exit): 9

1ssssssss
s2sssssss
ss3ssssss
sss4sssss
ssss5ssss
sssss6sss
ssssss7ss
sssssss8s
ssssssss9

Enter a positive number less than 10 (0 - exit): 8

1sssssss
s2ssssss
ss3sssss
sss4ssss
ssss5sss
sssss6ss
ssssss7s
sssssss8

Enter a positive number less than 10 (0 - exit): 7

1ssssss
s2sssss
ss3ssss
sss4sss
ssss5ss
sssss6s
ssssss7

Enter a positive number less than 10 (0 - exit): 6

1sssss
s2ssss
ss3sss
sss4ss
ssss5s
sssss6

Enter a positive number less than 10 (0 - exit): 5

1ssss
s2sss
ss3ss
sss4s
ssss5

Enter a positive number less than 10 (0 - exit): 4

1sss
s2ss
ss3s
sss4

Enter a positive number less than 10 (0 - exit): 3

1ss
s2s
ss3

Enter a positive number less than 10 (0 - exit): 2

1s
s2

Enter a positive number less than 10 (0 - exit): 1

1

Enter a positive number less than 10 (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop count from 1 to num and add an `else` to your `if` that prints the number.

Answer (score 0):

The precision field, `%.precision`, can be use to print a specific number of characters and an asterisk provides a means to use a variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int each = 0;
    char s[] = { "ssssssss"};

    for ( each = 0; each < 6; each++) {
        printf ( "%.*s%d%.*s\n", each, s, each + 1, 5 - each, s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```